# xamarin IOS ReadToEnd() on stream from HttpWebResponse not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have this code which is working fine in Android after I get a response from web service but fails in IOS. It was also working fine in ISO before I updated Visual studio. It fails during  `reader.ReadToEnd()`

```
 try
{                 
   HttpWebResponse response=GetWebResponseAsync(); 
}        
catch (exception ex)
{
   var stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream();
   using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
  {
     retVal.ResponseText = reader.ReadToEnd();//It fails during 
      ReadToEnd() 
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you upload failure details properly do you get an exception? If yes can I see the stacktrace.

Comment: @G.hakim System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (ReadAsync): ReceiveFailure Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: src

Comment: Add the full exception stack trace to your question please

Comment: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: src

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53592318/xamarin-ios-readtoend-on-stream-from-httpwebresponse-not-working?noredirect=1#comment94075964_53592318